# Cloud Data Fusion - Scheduling with different parameter value

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am creating a Cloud Data Fusion pipeline, which needs to be invoke every hour and each time I need to create 2 instances of the same pipeline but with different runtime argument(Json file to GCS Argument Setter)
For example :

```
Schedule Time  Pipeline        Argument
10:00          myPipeline      gs://mybucket/argument1.json
10:00          myPipeline      gs://mybucket/argument2.json
11:00          myPipeline      gs://mybucket/argument1.json
11:00          myPipeline      gs://mybucket/argument2.json
```

I know I can duplicate the pipeline and invoke, checking whether there is any way to run the same pipeline with different parameter? (Running one at 10:00 and other at 10:01 also would work)

Comment: If you simply want to pass arguments to the pipeline, you can do so using [runtime arguments](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1188036746/Runtime+Arguments). If you're using an external service (such as Cloud Functions) to invoke the pipeline, then runtime arguments will work for your use case. I don't think it's possible to solve your use case using only the built-in scheduling system.

Comment: @DennisLi Thank you for the comment, is there anyway I can pass parameter via REST API ? I see that we can start the pipeline, but I dont see option to give parameter during runtime via REST API

Comment: Could you describe a bit your use case? What is what you are trying to accomplish? If you could outline the structure of your pipeline that would be helpful

Comment: @Thelight According to the CDAP documentation, you can pass the runtime arguments as a JSON map in the request body. See https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477560983/Lifecycle+Microservices#Start-a-Program for additional details